# Is there a shortcut for this in Lens?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Is there a shortcut for this in the lens library?

```
\x -> liftM (^. x) get
```

Maybe it's a silly question, but it feels like a basic enough construction that there should be a shortcut for it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try [`use`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.1/docs/Control-Lens-Getter.html#v%3ause)

```
use :: MonadState s m => Getting a s a -> m a
use = gets . view
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! I didn't even know about gets before.